# Java string pool test doesn't work

Tags: java, string, pool

After reading about Java String Pool I've decided to run a little test.
I've written the following test program that it's result doesn't match the Java String Pool behavior according to the JDK specification.

```
public class Temp_20141220 {

    private String b1 = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Temp_20141220 t = new Temp_20141220();
        String b = "hello";
        System.out.println("b==b1 =" + t.b1 == b);
    }
}
```

I've been expecting to get in output: b==b1 =true
but I got: b==b1 =false

Why so? Does Ubuntu's JVM not support this Java String Pool feature?

Comment: Please provide code of Temp_20141220 class.

Answer (score 9):

This

```
System.out.println("b==b1 =" + t.b1 == b);
```

is equivalent to

```
System.out.println( ("b==b1 =" + t.b1) == b);
```

You're applying reference equality between `b` and the concatenation of `"b==b1 ="` and `t.b1`.

Comment: @JigarJoshi Thank you! It was a nice Christmas gift :)

Answer (score 3):

you're comparing 2 different strings:

1. string is `"b==b1 =" + t.b1`
2. string is b

if you change your code to:

```
System.out.println("b==b1 =" + (t.b1 == b));
```

you will get true in output